# Django non-rel - how do I install it?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

As a new python and django developer, I'm creating a Django app on Google app engine.
Today I realized GAE helper did not support model formsets - after some research, I understand Django non-rel  is the best helper patch for Django _ GAE

So I downloaded it : but I cannot find instructions on how to install it - I've spend over an hour searching and searching - but there is no instructions!!!

I even found instructions on installing Django on non-rel download but not of non-rel -

1. How do I install Django non-rel?
2. do I need Django 1.3 - if so how can I install 1.3 in a way that I can deploy it to GAE since GAE has Django 1.2 native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the instructions are a little hidden and you can not find it via django-nonrel for some reason. Look for django-appengine instead. Check [this tutorial about django-appengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine). There you will also find all the installation instructions, how to use it and what to keep in mind when using it.

And about your specific question (1). You must use the modified Django 1.3 version of django-appengine (everything described in the link above). Don't use the official Django version. Also it must be in your project directory to work properly with GAE.

Comment: this really helps - thanks.
I've followed the instructions but I'm getting errors still.  It seems as if Django 1.2 library that comes with google app engine is being referenced instead of the local django I copied from non-rel.  I had used django 1.2 previously.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled GAE sdk but the result is the same.  What setting am I missing?

Here is some of the error I get when opening the testapp that comes with non-rel:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4053, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3977, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 588, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3050, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2954, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2836, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    script_module.main()

Comment: It seems to me you are running GAE with `dev_appserver.py`? Don't do this. If you use django-nonrel then you need to run you App Engine Server with the modified `manage.py` file within their testapp. This works like usually in Django (`manage.py runserver` for example) and it will wrap `dev_appserver`. Also it has a couple extra management commands for deploying to app engine for example (everything in the link).

Comment: I think that was one of the problems but still I'm getting the same issue.  from the local directory of testapp I ran the server as python manage.py runserver - It seems the server is looking in to django_1_2 folder under app engine before the local files, therefor giving different but similair error to before:

Comment: C:\App Engine\testapp >python manage.py runserver

WARNING:root:No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL cer
tificates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\utils\imp
ortlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

Comment: File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\App Engine\testapp\djang
oappengine\management\commands\runserver.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db import connections
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\db\__init
__.py", line 77, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\db\utils.
py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\db\utils.
py", line 50, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'dbindexer' isn't an available data
base backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named dbindexer.base

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\App Engine\testapp>

Comment: Finally - figured it out :
Installing on Windows XP:
1) rename modules correctly
2) dbindexer, autoload, djangotoolbox are nested.  after unziping for example autoload, there is a subdirectory autoload/autoload - I cut and paste the nested directory one level down - I did it for the other directories also - just look at the error and you can see which directories are effected - All worked after I fixed the nesting issue - Really wonder why it's setup that way?

Comment: Sorry commenting so late, but didn't had time. Good that you figured everything out. About this nested directory structure. That's how Python packages work. Usually you create a package and within a module (many times with the same name). To actually use the module the right way you either have to just copy the module in your directory (not the rest of the package) or setup it in your PYTHONPATH. Since its nonrel there is only the copy option so no real way you can know about it if you didn't use python packaging before.

Answer (score 1):

As for **2012 Q2**:

- Django 1.4 was released
- Django-nonrel based on Django 1.3 was moved to [github.com/django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel)
- Django-nonrel has a install script [django-nonrel-start-project](https://github.com/mczenko/django-nonrel-start-project)